# How to redirect all emails to a specific domain to one inbox

Tags: email

I searched around and couldn't find an answer so I'm asking, please direct me to the right place if it's been asked before.

Anyway, the question is, how to I redirect "anything@domain.com" to "specific@domain.com"

So that no matter what you put in front of the "@" sign it gets forwarded to that one specific email address.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the provider. Google has a guide to [setting up a catch-all address for Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33962?hl=en).

Comment: I'm not using google apps. I've got a tiny little server that everything is hosted on.

Comment: Then contact your webhost or if you manage the email server yourself, look for a guide to setting up a catch all address for that specific server software.